# forest trees: rounded rectangle nodes overlap

Tags: forest

I am drawing a tree with the help of the [`forest` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest). Some of my nodes use TikZ's `rounded rectangle` style ([see manual p.458](http://archive.cs.uu.nl/mirror/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf#page=458)).
However, the round sides of those nodes overlap. How do I fix that?

[image: overlapping nodes]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    point/.style={
        coordinate,
    },
    symbol/.style={
        draw=black,
        text height=1.5ex,
        text depth=.25ex,
    },
    terminal/.style={
        symbol,
    },
    nonterminal/.style={
        symbol,
        rounded corners,
    },
    operation/.style={
        symbol,
        rounded rectangle,
    },
[{Sequential},nonterminal
    [{Sequential},nonterminal
        [{$F_i$},operation]
        [{$F_{i+1}$},operation]
    ]
    [{},point
        [{$F_{i+2}$},operation]]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

PS: I'm using TikZ v3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The bug described here is fixed in version v1.05 (2014/03/07) of `forest` package.

It seems that the `rounded rectangle` option applied to some node is a problem with `forest` package: `forest` computes the node boundary of a `rounded rectangle` node as a `rectangle` node (using only `north east`, `north west`, `south east` and `south west` anchors). It is a bug in `forest`!

Here is a patch to `forest` (and a solution to your problem):

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
% --------- patch -----------
\makeatletter
\csdef{forest@compute@node@boundary@rounded rectangle}{%
  \forest@mt{east}%
  \forest@lt{north east}%
  \forest@lt{north}%
  \forest@lt{north west}%
  \forest@lt{west}%
  \forest@lt{south west}%
  \forest@lt{south}%
  \forest@lt{south east}%
  \forest@lt{east}%
}
\makeatother
% --------- end of patch -----------

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  point/.style={
    coordinate,
  },
  symbol/.style={
    draw=black,
    text height=1.5ex,
    text depth=.25ex,
  },
  terminal/.style={
    symbol,
  },
  nonterminal/.style={
    symbol,
    rounded corners,
  },
  operation/.style={
    symbol,
    rounded rectangle,
  },
  [{Sequential},nonterminal
    [{Sequential},nonterminal
     [{$F_i$},operation]
     [{$F_{i+1}$},operation]
    ]
    [{},point
      [{$F_{i+2}$},operation]]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can exploit `s sep`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={s sep=(2-level)*8mm},       %%% here
    point/.style={
        coordinate,
    },
    symbol/.style={
        draw=black,
        text height=1.5ex,
        text depth=.25ex,
    },
    terminal/.style={
        symbol,
    },
    nonterminal/.style={
        symbol,
        rounded corners,
    },
    operation/.style={
        symbol,
        rounded rectangle,
    },
[{Sequential}, s sep=8mm,nonterminal  %%% here
    [{Sequential},nonterminal
        [{$F_i$},operation]
        [{$F_{i+1}$},operation]
    ]
    [{},point
        [{$F_{i+2}$},operation]]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This answer is a workaround of a bug in `forest`.